# Chrome and Brave browser lagging in Windows 11

Tags: windows, google-chrome, browser, internet, windows-11

I've been experiencing some performance issues with Google Chrome and Brave Browser on my Windows 11 computer. Interestingly, when I run Chrome or Brave as an administrator, it seems to work smoothly without any lag. However, when I run regular, it lags quite a bit. I've already tried enabling and disabling hardware acceleration, but it hasn't resolved the issue.

Browser is also updated to latest version. I also tried to uninstall and install, but same issue facing again.

Any ideas why this might be happening and how I can resolve it? I'd appreciate any insights or solutions you can provide. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try fresh user profiles?

Comment: Interesting... and since I noticed that Firefox seems slow recently (on a high-speed connection), I tried running it as Admin and I perceive an improvement on Windows 10! However, I'll try some test sites to confirm the speed difference.